# Redis data not showing up until Node.js child_process.fork() completes

Tags: node.js, redis, polling, child-process

I am forking a child process in a server app which does some repetitive CPU-bound work, a status value is pushed to Redis on every iteration.

The problem is that the status value does not show up on Redis until the child process completes, so I am only able to fetch the last status value.

I am polling for status value in a client app.

I'm using node_redis as Redis client.

I have verified the non-existence of status values before child process completion from redis-cli too.

**parent (server app):**

```
child_process.fork('child.js')
```

**child (server app):**

```
for (...) {
    //CPU-bound work
    redisClient.hset(key, field, value)
}
```

**client app:**

```
(function poll () {
    //wait
    redisClient.hget(key, field)
    poll()
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your child code to

```
async.eachSeries(data, function(element, next) {
   //do cpu bound work on element
   redisClient.hset(key, field, value, next); // wait for callback before starting next work
}, function(err) {
   console.log('done');
});
```

If you don't wait for the hset command callback what happens is the for loop will just keep going and won't get a chance to update the status. You might need to use a better [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#collections).* method for your needs.

Comment: Fixed by simply using callbacks on Redis commands. Just saw your suggestion of using an async library, I don't think I need that in my situation. Thanks anyways!